# Levene's Test in R

Tags: r

I was using Levene's test to check the equality of variance in R. For this I installed the `car` package. I used the following command in R for this:

```
install.packages("car")
```

After running this command I got the following message:

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/DELL/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> also installing the dependencies ‘magrittr’, ‘pkgconfig’, ‘R6’, ‘BH’, ‘rematch’, ‘assertthat’, ‘fansi’, ‘utf8’, ‘forcats’, ‘hms’, ‘readr’, ‘cellranger’, ‘zip’, ‘cli’, ‘crayon’, ‘pillar’, ‘rlang’, ‘SparseM’, ‘MatrixModels’, ‘sp’, ‘haven’, ‘curl’, ‘data.table’, ‘readxl’, ‘openxlsx’, ‘tibble’, ‘minqa’, ‘nloptr’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘RcppEigen’, ‘carData’, ‘abind’, ‘pbkrtest’, ‘quantreg’, ‘maptools’, ‘rio’, ‘lme4’

In this list of dependencies, all the packages got installed except `Rcpp`. After this process, I tried to run the Levene's test and got the following error message

```
library(car)
leveneTest(Minimum1 ~ Type)

Error in leveneTest(Minimum1 ~ Type) :
could not find function "leveneTest"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. *all the packages got installed except "Rcpp" package*. Maybe try to install this package?

Comment: Levene test is something very simple, no way it could depend on Rcpp. And look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html -- `car` package depends only on `carData` -- there are *no* other dependencies. Definitely no `magrittr` ... and definitely no `Rcpp` in the list. Something is wrong .... I would first try `install.packages` again

Comment: try `search()` right after `library(car)`. Can you see `"package:car" ` in second position? If yes, try  `ls(2)`. What do you see?

Comment: After you run `library(car)`, what does `sessionInfo()` show? That will list all the loaded packages and their versions. That might help us determine what's going on (edit your question to include that output)

Comment: @lebatsnok : while I am running the library(car), I got the following message : > library(car)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

Comment: @lebatsnok : I tried the search(), after library(car).........and found the "package:carData"  in second position....After this I tried ls(2) and got the following results..............> ls(2)
 [1] "Adler"           "AMSsurvey"       "Angell"          "Anscombe"        "Arrests"        
 [6] "Baumann"         "BEPS"            "Bfox"            "Blackmore"       "Burt"           
............................     
[61] "Wool"            "WVS"  .............................................................          
 what's it mean, I didn't understand

Comment: @MrFlick: I tried the sessionInfo() after library(car) and got the following output........................................................................................                  attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] carData_3.0-2

It shows the carData package ........but while running levenes test I got the same error message...........

Comment: Well... it's clear that the problem is with your installation of `car`. Something is clearly wrong, as (1) `car` is not attached to your search path -- this can be seen from `search()`; (2) `car` does not depend on `Rcpp` or any other packages listed in OP.  That is, loading `car` (with `library(car)`) should in no way depend on `Rcpp` and fixing your issues with `Rcpp` will not help you. Before doing anything else, I would try `install.packages("car")` again. Maybe it is installed correctly then and the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Install 'hsm' package by using (`install.packages("hms")`) before loading 'car' package